# Setting JVM arguments at runtime

Tags: java, eclipse

I keep getting the following error when I run my program:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : Java heap space

I tried fixing this by adding `-Xms512M -Xmx1524M` to both Program arguments and VM arguments (I use eclipse), but this doesn't seem to prevent the error.

If the solution is adding more memory in eclipse run configuration, the question is > *is this going to be exported too?* or is it just for me, how can I make sure this doesn't happen on other computers?

## Current code

```
 private static void checkSumGen() throws IOException NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {

    File plFolder = new File(".\\Plugins");
    File[] listOfFiles = plFolder.listFiles();
    List<String> listClone = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
        {
            File file = listOfFiles[i];
            String fileloc = file.getAbsolutePath();
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileloc);

            byte[] dataBytes = new byte[1024];

            int nread = 0;
            while ((nread = fis.read(dataBytes)) != -1)
            {
                md.update(dataBytes, 0, nread);
            } ;
            byte[] mdbytes = md.digest();
                
            // convert the byte to hex format method 1
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < mdbytes.length; i++)
                {
                    sb.append(Integer.toString((mdbytes[i1] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1)); 
                }

            System.out.println("Hex format : " + sb.toString());

            // convert the byte to hex format method 2
            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < mdbytes.length; i++)
                {
                    hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & mdbytes[i2]));
                }
            System.out.println("Hex format : " + hexString.toString());
        }

}
```

Comment: Don't you want to read the input file not the data bytes you create?

Comment: @kpie please make the question more clear.

Comment: what's going on on the line that reads `while ((nread = fis.read(dataBytes)) != -1)`

Comment: @kpie See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read-byte:A-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in your code that causes the `OutOfMemoryError`.

In:

```
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < mdbytes.length; i++)
```

you increment `i` instead of `i1` causing `i1 < mdbytes.length` to be `true` forever.

Comment: Works, thanks. Also I want to point out that the same error was made on the last for loop as I used `i++` instead of `i2++` .